# How can I strip a currency character that may appear in the beginning or end of a string column value?

Tags: python, dataframe, special-characters

I have a pandas dataframe column called Cost that may have values like £2394.21 or 2435.68£ or $1753.32 or 7854$. I want to extract the currency sign, which could be at the beginning or end, and store it in a new column. How can I  achieve that?

Added to the complication I have no idea what encoding is used to store these symbols. I tried to find the position of the currency symbol within the column and store it in a new column called 'indexes'. The code below returns indexes as -1 because I may not be checking £ or $ with the correct encoding.

```
sub = '£'
df['indexes'] = df['Cost'].str.find(sub)
sub = '$'
df['indexes'] = df['Cost'].str.find(sub)
```

I want to extract the currency symbol from Cost column and store it in a new column.

e.g. 
    df['currency'] = df['Cost].str(df['indexes'])

Comment: You probably can use regular expressions to find any non-number character and replace it with empty string

Comment: And then use the same regex but inverted to find currency character and save it to another column

Answer (score 0):

Store the currency symbols in a list. Then, iterate over the list and check for the presence of each `currency` in the `df['Cost']` series. For every element found, strip the `currency` from the found element in the row and assign the `currency` value to the corresponding row in `df['currency']`.

```
currencies = ['$', '£']
for currency in currencies:
    if df['Cost'].str.contains(currency):
        df['Cost'].str.strip(currency)
        df['currency'] = currency
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I answered in a hurry. I've just added some explanation.